# How to get posts on a specific date - WP Query

Tags: wp-query, mysql

I want to get posts of a specific date, I tried the following code but I did not get the result what I wanted.

```
<?php
$mil = 1532996880000;
$seconds = $mil / 1000;
$dt = date( "Y-m-d", $seconds );

$post_by_date = $wpdb->get_row("
    SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts}
    WHERE post_date = $dt
    AND post_status = 'publish'
");
```

**WP QUERY**

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'date' => $dt,
    'posts_per_page' => 1
));
```

---

This did not work because, the output of `$dt = 2018-07-31`, but the output shows no results. Because it compares with `2018-07-31 09:09:40`. So is there any way to get posts of a specific date?

Comment: This is pure PHP question, you an easily get  2018-07-31 from 2018-07-31 09:09:40 using PHP

Comment: But if I use this method then I will have to compare each and every row in db and will have to get the date only.....this will take some amount of time

Comment: What do you plan to do with `$post_by_date`?

Comment: I just want the post data of a specific date and return the post data. Thats it! @MaxYudin

Comment: Can't it be done by wp-query? https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
//  primarily get $year, $month and $day
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        'year'  => $year,
        'month' => $month,
        'day'   => $day,
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        // do whatever here

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I think this is the only way I can do it. Thank you Max

Answer (score 1):

> Please use date query for that also use below code hope it will work for you

```
$mil = 1532996880000;
$seconds = $mil / 1000;
$dt = date( "Y-m-d", $seconds );
 $year =  date( "Y", $seconds );
 $month =  date( "m", $seconds ); 
 $day =  date( "d", $seconds );


$args = array(
 'date_query' => array(
  array(
   'year'  => $year,
   'month' => $month,
   'day'   =>$day,
  ),
 ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```